# polynomial ring prime element

Tags: ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials, prime-factorization

Let $Q = \sum_{j=0}^n \alpha_j X^j$ be a polynomial with integer coefficients and $\alpha_n = 1$.
Show that $Q$ is a prime element of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ if and only if $Q$ is a prime element of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

My ideas: By definition, $Q$ is prime element means $Q \neq 0, Q \notin R^*$ and $Q = ab \Rightarrow Q|a$ or $Q|b$.

Now, I don't know how to continue.

(1) Because the coefficients of $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ are from an integral domain it can be proven that $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ is also an integral domain.

(2) A prime element of an integral domain is always irreducible. By definition, this means $Q = ab \Rightarrow a \in \mathbb{Z}[X]^*$ or $b \in \mathbb{Z}[X]^*$.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do $R^\ast$, $\Bbb Z[X]^\ast$ mean?

Comment: Have you ever heard about “Gauss’ Lemma”?

Comment: @egreg I just wanted to let you know (a bit late though) that your hint solved my problem. I am, however, not able to accept your answer because I don't see an option for this here.

Comment: @Pagenotfound I added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ring $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ is not only a domain, but a [*unique factorization domain*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_factorization_domain) (hence irreducible elements coincide with prime elements) for which [Gauss’ lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_(polynomial)) holds.

In the particular case of $a_n=1$, the polynomial cannot have noninvertible integer factors, so by Gauss’ lemma it is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ if and only if it is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$.